# Joining two tables in sql j with non matching rows when rows are absent in one of the two tables

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

i have two tables that have count of items sold. i need to compare these two tables and fetch records that are not matching, sum of item sold in one table is not equal to quantity of units sold in other table

```
select * from 
(select sum(units) AS UNITS, item, location, tran_date from tran_data_history where tran_date  = '' and tran_code = 1 group by item, location,tran_date)A,
(select sum(qty) AS QTY, item, store from sa_tran_item where  tran_Seq_no =''
)B
where A.item = B.item and A.location = B.store and A.UNITS <> B.QTY;
```

it is giving me rows where count of items not matching in both tables. but i want those item, store combination also which are present in one table and not present in another.

eg
tran_data_history

```
item location units
11     a        5
22      b        1
33      c        4
```

sa_tran_item

```
item  store  qty
11      a     4
33      c      4
```

in sa_tran_item, item 33 is not posted, i want to display rows

```
item  store  qty  units
11      a     4    5
22      b      0    1
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from 
(select sum(units) AS UNITS, item, location, tran_date from tran_data_history where tran_date  = '' and tran_code = 1 group by item, location,tran_date) A
    full outer join 
(select sum(qty) AS QTY, item, store from sa_tran_item where  tran_Seq_no ='')B
on A.item = B.item and A.location = B.store 
where A.UNITS <> B.QTY;
```

Comment: this query is still not fetching me rows where item store combination present in sa_tran_item table and not present in tran_data_history

Comment: Does it fetch them when the where clause is omitted?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a computer with DB installed on it right now, but it appears that you want to do a FULL OUTER JOIN.  Please see FULL OUTER JOIN section of [SQL JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_join) Wikipedia entry.  This code should allow you to meet your requirements:

```
select 
    * 
from 
    (
        select 
            sum(units) AS UNITS
            , item
            , location
            , tran_date 
        from 
            tran_data_history 
        where 
            tran_date  = '' 
            and tran_code = 1 
        group by 
            item
            , location
            ,tran_date
    )A
FULL OUTER JOIN
    (
        select 
            sum(qty) AS QTY
            , item
            , store 
        from 
            sa_tran_item 
        where  
            tran_Seq_no =''
    )B 
 ON
 A.item = B.item 
 and A.location = B.store
 and and A.UNITS <> B.QTY
/
```

Comment: Its not working for me, as its fetching RECORDS WHERE EITHER OF tables is having null records. i want records which are not matching in sum of quantities or records which are present in one table and absent in other.